# How do I prevent an odd powershell yellow-on-green automatic web-related message?

Tags: powershell

I created the following Powershell code in a script that works fine:

```
$ErrorActionPreference='silentlycontinue'
...
while ($true) {
...
    $capture = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "http://AnyValidWebsiteUrl"
...
}
```

I never set or alter the color of text or text messages in any manner.  Yet I get Yellow text on a greenish background that at first just very briefly flashes there very rapidly in the Powershell console window, but then later starts remaining and somewhat accumulating just below the top console text-line, with the normally-displayed text in the white-on-black background continuing to scroll beneath it as if this special yellow-on-green text isn't really there.  This special text obviously deals with the web response and states the following (with it eventually repeating these two lines below it with more and more of them as the time increases although the bottom-most pair always gets erased repeatedly for some time before it adds a new pair below it):

```
Reading Web Response
   Reading response stream... (Number of bytes read: ####This being some byte count)
```

So, as you can see, I should be "silently continuing" without displaying any type of messages at all to my understanding so far.  Any ideas why this text would be showing up in connection with reading the webpages and how I might prevent it, especially being that it eventually when left running long enough in this loop will eat up the entire console window with this special yellow-on-green text?  I'm happy with my script and will not be changing it in any major ways so am simply seeking technical details as to what is happening here and how, if possible, I might stop this yellow-on-green text from appearing during this process.  Thanks...

====================

Thank you, Mathias R. Jessen, I appreciate it!  I've added this into my code now and will look forward to the improvement.  I'd searched on yellow text and only came up with things about how to set the color of your text in Powershell.  I'm a beginning user of Powershell.  I just wish that I didn't need this script, however, which I'm using to combat a bad situation between my Windows 8 computer and a flaky public WiFi in my apartment.  It's odd, because my Windows XP stays connected to the same WiFi okay but my Windows 8 computer usually keeps losing its connection to it about every 3 minutes.  So I'm using a script to reset the adapter each time so that I don't have to do it manually, which itself takes about 3 minutes for the disabling to be acknowledged.  For now, however, I'll stick with the script since it does help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "special" yellow-on-green text you're seeing is the `powershell.exe` implementation of a progress bar!

If you want to hide it completely, suppress progress events with the `$ProgressPreference` automatic variable:

```
$ErrorActionPreference='SilentlyContinue'
$ProgressPreference='SilentlyContinue'
...
while ($true) {
...
    $capture = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "http://AnyValidWebsiteUrl"
...
}
```